# Simple way to resize a DIV with Javascript/Prototype

Tags: javascript, resize, prototypejs

I have a div that floats at the bottom of the screen and want to let users vertically resize it (by grabbing a handle on the top of the div and pulling the div up or down).  I am using Prototype.js, so it just has to be compatible with that, though if there is a simpler way of doing it than with yet another javascript library that would be much preferred.  Anyone found anything like this or have a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cfchris.com/cfchris/index.cfm/2009/2/18/How-To-Prototype-Drag-Corner) is what you are looking for. It has the sample code using prototype.